# Story about space explorers who communicate but then decide they must destroy each other

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm looking for a sci-fi story or novel from many years ago where a deep space explorer encounters an alien explorer. The explorers learn to communicate; but on parting, each decides to destroy the other in order to protect his own world.

Comment: This sounds superficially like [Enemy Mine](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/enemy-mine-barry-b-longyear/1000119674), by Barry B. Longyear.  It was made into [a movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089092/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) in 1985.

Comment: Eh, that sounds like *the opposite* of Enemy Mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The story is probably ["First Contact"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41398), a famous novelette by ["Murray Leinster"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murray_Leinster) (pen name of William Fitzgerald Jenkins) which was also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19714/short-story-about-first-encounter-with-aliens). The plot is just as you described it, except that it has a happy ending: they figure out a way to go home without destroying each other and without giving away the locations of their home planets. (The October 6, 1955
[*X Minus One*](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles/XMinusOne55-10-06020FirstContact.mp3) radio adaptation is somewhat closer to your description. Another radio adaptation, the January 15, 1958 episode of [*Exploring Tomorrow*](https://archive.org/details/Exploring_Tomorrow/ET_58-01-15_0006_First_Contact.mp3), is more faithful to the original written story.) Here is the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Contact_(novelette)) plot summary:

> Space travel is routine between planets in the Solar System. Ships function very much like naval warships or research vessels. There are technologies such as "overdrive" which allows a ship to travel much faster than light in normal space, and apparently artificial gravity within a ship. Atomic power is used everywhere, even in a space suit propulsion unit. Ships are equipped with "blasters", not necessarily for use as weapons, but for destroying space debris which would otherwise collide with the ship.
>
> The exploration ship *Llanvabon* is approaching the Crab Nebula when it suddenly detects another ship on its radar. The two ships' radars are, in fact, interfering with each other, so each sees a wildly distorted image of the other ship. Even after the problem is resolved and the two crews, one human, one alien, establish communication, both realize they have a problem. Neither can leave without ensuring that the other cannot track them to their home planet.
>
> The aliens are humanoid bipeds, but see in the infrared portion of the spectrum. Also, instead of using sound to communicate among themselves they use microwaves emitted from an organ in their heads. As one human points out, "From our point of view, they have telepathy. Of course from their point of view, so do we."
>
> The crews discover they have much in common. This is especially true of young Tommy Dort and his counterpart on the other ship, to whom he has assigned the name Buck. Although they are only able to communicate through an artificial code, they are able to establish a rapport. However, Buck is pessimistic about the eventual outcome. He sends Tommy a message, "You are a good guy. Too bad we must kill each other."
>
> The deadlock persists. Neither ship dares to leave for fear that the other will be able to track it home. Neither captain is ready to gamble by attacking the other ship. Then Tommy realizes the way out of the impasse. He and his Captain arrange an exchange of personnel between the ships. Tommy and the Captain go aboard the alien ship even as two aliens board the *Llanvabon*. Then they present an ultimatum: they will detonate the atomic power packs in their suits if the aliens refuse to go along with their plan, which is for each crew to take the other's ship back to their home planet. Each will disable all the tracking equipment on their own ship before the exchange, and indeed they will have to be thorough to prevent the new crew from tracking them.
>
> At this point the aliens begin behaving very strangely, twitching or lying down and kicking the floor. In fact this is their equivalent of laughter. Their own people have just given the humans the same ultimatum, and the same plan.
>
> The story ends with each crew taking over the other's ship. Naturally, before leaving their own ship they are able to remove everything which might point back to their home world. Each stands to benefit from the new technology on the other's ship. Each keeps the other race's fiction library to gain insight into their thinking. They agree to repeat the encounter at the same location some time in the future.
>
> Tommy is confident that the two races will get along. He believes this because, as he tells the Captain, he and Buck spent a good deal of time swapping dirty jokes.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative candidate is Gordon R. Dickson's ["Sleight of Wit"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55511).

Short summary:

> A somewhat anarchical (or at least very messy) lonely explorer<sup>1</sup> finds a new planet, and looks for the best place to land. When it arrives there it finds that there is already a ship, only when he has landed he finds it the ship is not human and (in contrast to his own), the alien ship appears to have weapons.
>
> For several days the alien (the alien ship has only a pilot, too) and the human have a kind of a standoff; both of them want to go home and warn their races but none of them want the other to leave; and the human as bluffed the alien into believing that his ship has weapons.
>
> They meet in the middle ground several times (including a session singing and playing guitar) and finally they agree to inspect each other ships. Turns out the human had rigged a coffee maker to start when his door was opened, and counted on the alien not being aware for the coffee maker to explode and stun the alien.
>
> <sup>1</sup>At the beginning it is explained that the human pilot was used for PR advertisements, but showing immaculate ships that were nothing like the one he flew.

[It is online here](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/0743471741/0743471741___2.htm).